# Connecting from OpenVPN Server to MySQL Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server installed on a server.  What I'm trying to do connect from the OpenVPN server using the mysql client to the MySQL server than is connected to the OpenVPN server using a client.  I can ping back and forth between the servers, no issues.  However, if I use the MySQL client on the OpenVPN server to try to connect to the MySQL server I get a

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.8.0.6' (111)
```

with 10.8.0.6 being the connected to the OpenVPN server at 10.8.0.1.

I thought it might be IPTables but adding explicit INPUT and OUTPUT one the client and the server didn't change anything.  Telnet 10.8.0.6 3306 didn't work either.  I have verified that  MySQL is running on 3306:

```
me@db:~# lsof -i4 -P | grep -i mysql
mysqld  6192 mysql   10u  IPv4  40596      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
```

So what am I doing wrong?  Google has been less than helpful, as far as what I could find it should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MySQL server is listening only to localhost (127.0.0.1) so you can't connect to it from other servers. This is a default "safe" setting to prevent other machines from being able to connect to MySQL unless you explicitly allow it.

Edit your my.cnf file (probably in /etc/my.cnf) and change the bind-address from 127.0.0.1 to one of:

- The IP address of your MySQL server
- *0.0.0.0* to listen on all IPv4 addresses configured on the server
- *::* to listen on all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address

Comment: That's it.  The address binding was for 127.0.0.1, commented that out, restarted MySQL and it works.  Thanks.