# MySQL ERROR 2007 (HY000): Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, mysql, bridge

*It's not clear whether this has more to do with port collision or something related to "X protocol" and perhaps disabling "X protocol" or changing its welcome message.*

---

Might [this](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/1049) error [indicate](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/mysql-said-protocol-mismatch-server-version-11-client-version-10) a port collision? [As](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-shell/8.0/en/news-8-0-16.html):

> Functionality Added or Changed
>
> ```
> Important Change: Attempting to connect to an X Protocol port, 33060 by default, using the classic MySQL protocol resulted in the
> ```
>
> following error: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server
> at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
>
> ```
> This was because of differences in X Protocol and classic MySQL protocol clients expectations on how connections were initialized.
> ```
>
> Now, in such a situation the generated error message is ERROR 2007
> (HY000): Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10.
> If you encounter this error then you are probably trying to use the
> wrong port for the protocol your client is using.

The `alice` and `bob` containers were [created](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12508/23443) using `docker`, both are from the default `mysql-server` image on `docker` hub.  I'm [trying to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60195263/4531180) from `alice` to `bob` using the `MySQL` console.

Logged into `alice` from the host, after installing `iputils` and `telnet` with `yum`:

```
bash-4.2# 
bash-4.2# ping bob
PING bob (172.21.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bob.foo (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from bob.foo (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from bob.foo (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
^C
--- bob ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2047ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.064/0.078/0.086/0.009 ms
bash-4.2# 
bash-4.2# telnet bob
Trying 172.21.0.3...
telnet: connect to address 172.21.0.3: Connection refused
bash-4.2# 
bash-4.2# telnet bob 33060
Trying 172.21.0.3...
Connected to bob.
Escape character is '^]'.

�^CConnection closed by foreign host.
bash-4.2# 
bash-4.2# telnet bob 3306 
Trying 172.21.0.3...
Connected to bob.
Escape character is '^]'.
CHost '172.21.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host.
bash-4.2# 
bash-4.2# mysql mysql -h bob -P 33060 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2007 (HY000): Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10
bash-4.2#
```

How do I update the client version to 11?  From alice:

```
bash-4.2# 
bash-4.2# rpm -qa | grep mysql
mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch
mysql-shell-8.0.21-1.el7.x86_64
mysql-community-minimal-release-el7-1.noarch
mysql-community-server-minimal-8.0.21-1.el7.x86_64
bash-4.2#
```

and bob should be the same.

Or, is this a [security](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71082/101935) precaution?

---

I tried again, [specifying different ports](https://pastebin.com/5M6AnjL6) but with the same error.

see also:

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,684386,686543#msg-686543

Answer (score 1):

Make sure nothing else is running on that port. So stop mysql, and see if you can still get the same error. If so, something else is running on the port you try to use.